# StructureMap Plugins, calling init method when registered

Tags: structuremap

I am exploring the possibility of using [StructureMap](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm) to load all instances of my plugin type `IPlugin` from a specific directory using the Scan feature.

When a plugin is registered with StructureMap I would like to call an Init method that would register the plugin in the database if it was the first time it had been seen.

Is there a way to "foreach" through the registered IPlugins, obtain a reference and call Init on each one?

I am aiming for drag and drop plugin installation.

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: Can you explore more what you mean by drag and drop? Do you mean dropping assemblies on a watched directory? Do you mean at runtime to register types in a container based on user input? Just curious.

Comment: Sure. What I am after initially is being able to place plugins in a directory and they auto-register on app restart. I may want to extend in the future to a watched directory.

Comment: I do this in one of my apps. I'll thrown down another answer with some example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily look at all the plugins which are configured for the container using the Model property off the container. Here is an example with the **strong cavet**. This is likely not what you are looking for. It is just an example of a couple of the ways I dreamt up to initialize things that you register in the container.

```
public interface IInitable
{
    void Init();
    bool Inited { get; }
}

public abstract class Initable : IInitable
{
    public bool Inited { get; private set; }

    public void Init()
    {
        Inited = true;
    }
}

public class Initable1 : Initable { }
public class Initable2 : Initable { }

[TestFixture]
public class accessing_the_container_model
{
    [Test]
    public void put_things_in_and_init_then_during_construction()
    {
        var container = new Container(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.For<IInitable>().Use(c =>
            {
                var initable = c.GetInstance<Initable1>();
                initable.Init();
                return initable;
            });
        });

        container.GetAllInstances<IInitable>().Each(i => i.Inited.ShouldBeTrue());
    }

    [Test]
    public void put_things_in_and_init_them()
    {
        var container = new Container(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.For<IInitable>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Add<Initable1>();
            cfg.For<IInitable>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Add<Initable2>();
        });

        foreach (var instance in container.Model.GetAllPossible<IInitable>())
        {
            instance.Init();
        }

        container.GetAllInstances<IInitable>().Each(i=>i.Inited.ShouldBeTrue());
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great starting point. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using the assembly scanner is a great way to create a plug-in model.

```
public class StructuremapBootstrap
{
    public IContainer Container { get; private set; }

    public StructuremapBootstrap()
    {
        Container = new Container(x =>
        {
            //add registries here or do your config.

            //extensibility
            x.Scan(scan =>
            {
                                //some plugin discriminator
                scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(a => a.FullName.Contains("Plugin")); 

                scan.LookForRegistries();
                scan.AddAllTypesOf<IInitable>();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

You basically tell StructureMap to look for all the assemblies having a certain discriminator, I've also used a marker assembly attribute. The **LookForRegistries** scanner is handy to allow your plug-in assemblies to configure StructureMap as they please. Lastly you have the scanner add your desired plug-in type.